# SQLite Query to get sum_of_fields for every 10mins

Tags: html, sqlite

Hi i have the following table structure.

```
RESE_ID DATE_OF_SERVICE TIME_OF_SERVICE NO_OF_ATT_MALE  NO_OF_ATT_FEMALE
      1     2012-09-18       16:17:52        5                1
      2     2012-09-18       16:19:22        1                2
      3     2012-09-18       16:29:12        2                1
      4     2012-09-18       16:37:22        1                4
      5     2012-09-18       16:49:02        6                5
      6     2012-09-18       17:01:52        3                2
      7     2012-09-18       17:19:52        0                1
```

I just want the sum of (no_of_att_male) for every 10mins for last 1 hr for eg( 16:00 - 17:00 )

like the output shd be

```
  RESE_ID DATE_OF_SERVICE  NO_OF_ATT_MALE  NO_OF_ATT_FEMALE    TIME_SLOT
      1     2012-09-18             0                0        16:00 - 16:10   
      2     2012-09-18             6                3        16:11 - 16:20     
      3     2012-09-18             2                1        16:21 - 16:30   
      4     2012-09-18             1                4        16:31 - 16:40    
      5     2012-09-18             6                5        16:41 - 16:50   
      6     2012-09-18             0                0        16:51 - 17:00
```

kindly suggest me a query which will accept in sqlite ( i am using it in HTML5 )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Sure will delete the old question which is not relavent. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_OF_SERVICE,
       SUM(NO_OF_ATT_MALE),
       SUM(NO_OF_ATT_FEMALE),
       SUBSTR(TIME_OF_SERVICE, 1, 4) || '0 - ' ||
       SUBSTR(TIME_OF_SERVICE, 1, 4) || '9'       AS TIME_SLOT
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 4
```

This will result in an output like this, i.e., no records for empty time slots:

```
DATE_OF_SERVICE  SUM(NO_OF_ATT_MALE)  SUM(NO_OF_ATT_FEMALE)  TIME_SLOT
---------------  -------------------  ---------------------  -------------
2012-09-18       6                    3                      16:10 - 16:19
2012-09-18       2                    1                      16:20 - 16:29
2012-09-18       1                    4                      16:30 - 16:39
2012-09-18       6                    5                      16:40 - 16:49
2012-09-18       3                    2                      17:00 - 17:09
2012-09-18       0                    1                      17:10 - 17:19
```

Comment: Stunning Excellent... I am getting the exact results but if both the column is 0 still i am getting it...is that correct ?

Comment: Hi CL, how can i improve the same query for twenty mintues interval ? thanks for your help. thats great.

Comment: It will show sums for all time slots for which records exist in the database. If there are 0/0 records, those will show up too.

Comment: To round to 20-minute intervals: `SELECT ... SUBSTR(TIME_SLOT,1,3) || (SUBSTR(TIME_SLOT,4,1) / 2 * 2) || '0' FROM mytable ...`

Comment: thanks for it CL> will try and let u know very soon any hw thank u so much.

Comment: HI I HAVE tried the same logic for 20 as follow. SELECT  SUBSTR(START_TIME_OF_SERVICE,1,3) || (SUBSTR(START_TIME_OF_SERVICE,4,1) / 2 * 2) || '0'||'-'||SUBSTR(START_TIME_OF_SERVICE,1,3) || ((SUBSTR(START_TIME_OF_SERVICE,4,1) / 2 * 2)+1) || '9' AS TIME_SLOT is this correct. if so what would be for 30 ? thank you so much.

Comment: You do understand that `/ 2 * 2` rounds to a multiple of two, don't you?

Comment: ya i can and this is the query i tried for 30 min interval. and it seems to work fine. thanks. SUM(NO_OF_INFANT_F) AS INFANT_F, SUBSTR(START_TIME_OF_SERVICE,1,3) || (SUBSTR(START_TIME_OF_SERVICE,4,1) / 3 * 3) || '0 '|| ' - ' || SUBSTR (START_TIME_OF_SERVICE,1,3) || ((SUBSTR(START_TIME_OF_SERVICE,4,1) / 3 * 3)+2) || '9'

Comment: Hi , one small thing. Time slot has been kind of static. if we run the query by 12.05, it will show the records from 12:00 - 12:09. but is it possiable to alter the query so that the time slot generates the time - slot from the current time. i.e if the current time is 12:01. the time slot shd be from 12:01 - 11:51 , 11:52 - 11:42 , 11:43 - 11:33. it shd display for last one hour from the current time. any possiablites. Kindly suggest me some query. it will very much help.

Comment: Thanks CL, its truely helpfull. i will tried it and will u know...you rock man.

Comment: Hi if you see the http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/73867/1 , u will come to know that the 1st value of "15:41:10" is wrongly showed up in "15:46:21 - 15:55:21" where it suppose to show in "15:36:17 - 15:45:17". kindly clarify when ur free thanks for your time.

Comment: I was rounding up, not down. Changed to subtract 10 minutes.

Comment: thanks CL. will try and let u know thanks for your big help. :)

Comment: Hi i have done some specific to get the datas between current time and last one hr. i.e( if current time is 12.30 , it shd display records only from 11:00 - 12.30 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/71810/1 can you check whether what i did is fine or anything  worng in it. thanks a lot

Comment: Hi how can i display the records which is in also zero in both Male and Female column. Kindly suggest me when ur free. Thanks.

Comment: Records with zero values are shown in the result. And if you have a new question, you should create a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/67957/1 here its not showing the work with "12:25:52" even if its with in last 1hr.Sure i will create new question from next time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i have created the spearete question in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560439/sqlite-query-need-to-tuned-a-bit CL. thanks a lot.